# Problema com manipulação de dados de variáveis

Tags: java

Gostaria de 'pegar', da classe `Botao`, o valor que esta guardado na variável `aux` e compará-la com uma string na classe `Janela`

```java
class Botao extends JButton{
    public String aux;
    Botao(Menu menu, Janela janela) {
            this.setText(menu.lista[menu.i]);
            menu.i++;    
        this.setFocusable(false);

        this.addActionListener(evt ->{
            menu.setVisible(false);
            aux = this.getText().toString();
            new Janela(this, menu);
        });
    }
}
class Janela extends JFrame{    
    String[] lista2 = {"ID", "Name", "BDay", "Menu"};
    public javax.swing.JComboBox listaBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox(lista2);
    Janela(Botao botao, Menu menu){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Botao btn = new Botao(menu, this);
        this.setSize(500, 600);
        this.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        JPanel topo = new JPanel();
        topo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        topo.add(listaBox);
        topo.add(new JTextField());
        topo.add(new JButton("pesquisar"));
        JPanel meio = new JPanel();
        meio.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));

        if(btn.aux == "medico") {
            meio.add(new JLabel("Nome"));
            meio.add(new JTextField());
            meio.add(new JLabel("CPF"));
            meio.add(new JTextField());
            meio.add(new JLabel("DataNasc"));
            meio.add(new JTextField());
            meio.add(new JLabel("Telefone"));
            meio.add(new JTextField());
            meio.add(new JLabel("E-mail"));
            meio.add(new JTextField());
            meio.add(new JLabel("OBS"));
            meio.add(new JTextField());
        }

        JPanel baixo = new JPanel();
        baixo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        baixo.add(new JButton());
        baixo.add(new JButton());
        baixo.add(new JButton());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(topo, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.8;
        this.add(meio, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;
        this.add(baixo, gbc);



        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Menu extends JFrame{
    int i = 0;
    String[] lista = {"medico", "remedio", "adm", "paciente", "enfermeira", "leito", "receita"};
    Janela janela;
    Botao medico = new Botao(this, janela);
    Botao remedio = new Botao(this, janela);
    Botao adm = new Botao(this, janela);
    Botao enfermeira = new Botao(this, janela);
    Botao paciente = new Botao(this, janela);
    Botao leito = new Botao(this, janela);
    Botao receita = new Botao(this, janela);
    Menu(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500, 600);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1));
        this.add(medico);
        this.add(remedio);
        this.add(adm);
        this.add(paciente);
        this.add(enfermeira);
        this.add(leito);
        this.add(receita);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Menu();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podemos ir por partes para resolver o problemas.

1. Para dar nome aos botões mais facilmente, basta passar o nome por **parâmetro:**

```java
    Botao medico = new Botao("medico", this, janela);
    Botao remedio = new Botao("remedio",this, janela);
    Botao adm = new Botao("adm", this, janela);
    Botao enfermeira = new Botao("enfermeira", this, janela);
    Botao paciente = new Botao("paciente", this, janela);
    Botao leito = new Botao("leito", this, janela);
    Botao receita = new Botao("receita", this, janela);
```

Assim, o vetor pode ser excluído, visto que ele estava causando problema:

```
 - String[] lista = {"medico", "remedio", "adm", "paciente", "enfermeira", "leito", "receita"};
```

2. Recebendo os **nomes** por parâmetro e colocando-os como nome de cada botão:

```java
    Botao(String name, Menu menu, Janela janela) {
            this.setText(name);  
            [...]
        }
    }
```

Agora a variável *aux* pode ser excluída, assim como a sua declaração:

```java
- public String aux;
- aux = this.getText().toString();
```

3. Tendo em vista que a classe **Botão** é recebido por **parâmetro** pela a classe Janela, no seu construtor:

```java
    class Janela extends JFrame{    
        [...]
        Janela(Botao botao, Menu menu){
        [...]
    }
}
```

Basta usar isso para fazer a comparação:

```java
    if(botao.getText() == "medico") {
        [...]
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, vc simplesmente salvou minha pele, lhe devo meu rim, amém